# TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable.

Tags: python-3.x

```
def lines(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line
    yield '\n'

def blocks(file):
    block = []
    for line in lines(file):
        if line.strip():
            block.append(line)
        elif block:
            yield ''.join(block).strip()
            block = []


with open(r'test_input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = lines(f)
    file = blocks(lines)
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

I got this error message:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

I don't know what happened. Does it because generator in python3.6 is different from 2.X?

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of your exception? It's not at all obvious to me which line that exception is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by this line:

```
lines = lines(f)
```

With this assignment, you're overwriting the `lines` generator function with its own return value. That means that when `blocks` tries to call `lines` again (which seems a little buggy to me, but not the main issue), it gets the generator object instead of the function it expected.

Pick a different name for the assignment, or just pass `f` to `blocks`, since it will call `lines` itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I  pass f to blocks directly just as you told. It works! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to Python3. This error exists with Python 2.6.

I do not know exactly what you try to do but your code do not throws error replacing `blocks` function with :

```
def blocks(file):
    block = []
    for line in file:  # here, replace lines(file) with file
        if line.strip():
            block.append(line)
        elif block:
            yield ''.join(block).strip()
            block = []
```

However, I don't understand what you try to do with `lines()`

If this answer is not suitable to you, I encourage you to edit your question with more detail on what the functions are supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. The problem was resolved. The next time I edit my question I will provide more detail. Thanks again.